# Angular 2 tutorial sources typescript mixed with compiled js/map

Tags: angular, typescript

As a newby in angular, I am doing the angular2  tutorial, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/, Tour of heroes.

The source folder is ./app, but will also contain the ts/map files when built!
This is ugly, because it's making a lot of file mixed with sources.

Can someone help me to configure :
1. the build  folder to be : ./build
2. the source folder to be : ./src/main/typescript

I have the same file structure & content aas defined in tutorial [TOUR OF HEROES](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html)